# how to use target state css in inside another target state css and child?

Tags: html, css

How it work with in the parent which already have target state ?

I have id divmain with target state and I have used another target state in his child  `id="insidemenu"` show it not working it working if it has no parent with target state like `id="menu"`.

```css
#divMain{
  display:none; 
  width:100vh;
  height:100vh; 
  background:#F00; 
  color:#fff;
}
#divMain:target{ 
  display:block; 
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#menu li ul{ display:none}
#menu li ul:target{display:block;}
#insidemenu li ul{ display:none}
#insidemenu li ul:target{display:block;}
```

```html
<a href="#divMain"> open</a>
<div id="divMain" > welcome <a href="#"> close</a>
  <ul id="insidemenu">
    <li><a href="#inside-home">home</a>
      <ul id="inside-home">
        <ii>
        <a href="#"> ABOUT</a></1i>
        <ii>
        <a href="#"> OVERVIEW </a></1i>
        <ii>
        <a href="#"> CARRIER</a></1i>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#inside-service">service</a>
      <ul id="inside-service">
        <ii>
        <a href="#"> software</a></1i>
        <ii>
        <a href="#"> software </a></1i>
        <ii>
        <a href="#"> software</a></1i>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#home">home</a>
    <ul id="home">
      <ii>
      <a href="#"> ABOUT</a></1i>
      <ii>
      <a href="#"> OVERVIEW </a></1i>
      <ii>
      <a href="#"> CARRIER</a></1i>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#service">service</a>
    <ul id="service">
      <ii>
      <a href="#"> software</a></1i>
      <ii>
      <a href="#"> software </a></1i>
      <ii>
      <a href="#"> software</a></1i>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Please check on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/rahul-kumartailor/pen/wvobbWL)